# Extracting a number from a text with selenium webdriver/java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

I am testing a webpage where the following message is displayed:

> "You still have X free messages out of 100"

where x can be any number smaller than 100. And every time the user sends a message, that number decreases by 1.

I am using Selenium webdriver with java for automating the tests and I need to know how I can extract the x from that text and turn it into an integer, so I can compare it with a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code. locate element according to your convenience and replace it with first line of code

```
 String OSNAMES= Driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH")).getAttribute("value");
 String[] parts = OSNAMES.split(" ");
 String OS = parts[3];
 int a=Integer.parseInt(OS);
 System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

> how I can extract the x from that text and turn it into an integer?

try `split()` and get 3rd element from the string.

```
int x=Integer.parseInt("You still have X free messages out of 100".split(" ")[3]);
```